# Prevent linked-in and tiwtter share to open in the same window

Tags: javascript, browser, popup, window

I use the same code(Except the height parameter) to open linked-in and twitter share windows

```
window.open(
        url,
        title,
        '_blank,directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,=no,width='
        + width + ', height=' + height + ', left=' + x + ',top=' + y
    );
```

But they are replace each other and not opened in separate windows.
How do i open them in different windows.

Comment: Are you giving them a different `title` in the second argument?

Comment: Thanks,post you answer i will check it as correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to the `window.open()` function gives a name to the window being opened. If you use the same name as an existing window then that window is re-used. You set that argument from your `title` variable, so make sure your `title` is *different* for your Twitter and Linked-in windows and then they'll open in separate windows.

(If you want a new window every time then set the second argument as `"_blank"`.)

Further reading: [MDN's `window.open()` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)